# model object used by angular formly does not change when I reassign the object

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I use formly to edit some objects I get from a server. When I'm done editing I hit save. When the server responds with the newly saved object, I reassign this new object to my model object that formly uses. But this new object won't be used by formly for some reason. Because when I then tried to edit & save the object again. The old object is being used by formly instead of the new one I assigned to my model object.

I have a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/quqaduhuzo/1/edit?js,console,output) that demonstrates this. I mocked the server responding with a different object by just having 2 different objects. When I submit my changes, I assign a different object to my model object. I expect the data to change to the new model when i submit.

Comment: i face a similar problem , did this get solved for you ?

Answer (score 0):

its seems like its getting updated with new model, since you are able to model 2 in the scope after you receive the response from server

please see the updated jsbin

http://jsbin.com/gewasosohu/edit?html,console,output